# Finding All Integers in such that $\phi(n)=80$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I don't know where to start with this problem so please help. The problem is:

Find all integers n such that $\phi(n) = 80$.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Find"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: You know a formula for $\varphi(n)$, right? That should be an obvious place to *start*, even if it's not obvious where to go from there.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** If the prime factorization of $n$ is $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$, then
$$\phi(n)=\phi(p_1^{a_1})\cdots\phi(p_r^{a_r})=p_1^{a_1-1}(p_1-1)p_2^{a_2-1}(p_2-1)\cdots p_r^{a_r}(p_r-1).$$
The prime factorization of $80$ is $2^4\cdot 5$. What are the possible ways the $2$'s and the $5$ can be distributed among the factors on the right side of this equation?