# Calculate all $n \in \Bbb N \setminus \{41\}$ such that $\phi(n)=40$?

Tags: totient-function

> I'm looking for an $n \in \Bbb N$ for which $\phi(n) = 40$ where $\phi$ is a Euler-Totient Function

I already found one, namely, $n=41$

How the calculate the $n's$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you claiming that prime numbers are not natural numbers?

Comment: @matemate: Do you mean : Is there any other $n$ for which $\phi(n)=40$ ?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR yes that's what I mean!

Comment: How is $41$ not a natural number? Here is a [table of $\phi$ values](http://primefan.tripod.com/Phi500.html), the next smallest with $\phi=40$ are $55$, $75$, $82$, $88$, $100$...

Comment: @Conifold is there any difference in calculating this than this approach?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261256/inverse-euler-totient-function

Comment: Calculating what? They simply calculated the values of $\phi(n)$ using Euler's formula and tabulated the results. Are you trying to find *all* $n$ with $\phi(n)=40$? There is a [lower bound on $\phi(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301837/152568), which implies that $n$ can not be more than $2\times40^2$.

Comment: @Conifold yes all   with ()=40

Comment: Then you should reword the question, and the method under the link is more effective than exhaustive search up to $1600$.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507449/number-theory-find-all-solutions-of-phin-16-and-phin-24), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573017/find-all-positive-integers-n-such-that-phin-10), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344468/finding-all-integers-in-such-that-phin-80?rq=1) and related ones how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ and $q$ and two distinct primes, then $\varphi(pq)=\varphi(p)\varphi(q)=(p-1)(q-1)$.

So if you choose $p=11$ and $q=5$ you're done !

---

Now you can search for *all* solutions. Using essentially the same method as described in the links given above, it is not difficult to prove that the set of solutions for the equation $\varphi(n)=40$ is :

> $$S=\{41,55,75,82,88,100,110,132,150\}$$

Comment: what about $75$?

Comment: Ooops ! Sorry, I missed a few more cases. Editing ...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ \phi (55)= \phi(11)\phi(5) = 10\times 4 =40$$ and

$$ \phi (100)= \phi(4)\phi(25) = 2\times 20 =40$$ as well.

That is the function is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

Use the multiplicative property of $\phi$:  if $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime then $\phi(nm)=\phi(n)\phi(m)$.

$40=2\times2\times2\times5*=2\times2\times10=4\times2\times5*=8\times5*=4\times10=20\times2.$

$*\phi(n)$ cannot be an odd number $> 1.$

If $\phi(n)=2$ then $n=3, 4, $ or $6;$ note that $6$ is not relatively prime to the others.

If $\phi(n)=4$ then $n=5, 8, 10, $ or $12.$

If $\phi(n)=10$ then $n=11$ or $22.$

If $\phi(n)=20$ then $n=25, 33, 44, 50, $ or $66.$

> $3\times4\times11;  5\times11, 5\times22, 8\times11, 10\times11, 12\times11;  3\times25, 4\times25, 6\times25, 4\times33; 41, 41\times2$

Answer (score 1):

For $1<n\in \Bbb N,$ if $n$ has exactly $m$ prime divisors then $$n=\prod_{j=1}^m(p_j)^{E(p_j)}$$ where $\{p_1,...,p_m\}$ is the set of all prime divisors of $n$, and each $E(p_j)\in \Bbb N.$ And then $$\phi(n)=\prod_{j=1}^m(p_j-1)(p_j)^{E(p_j)-1}.$$ If $\phi(n)=40$ then

(i).  For each odd $p_j$ we have $(p_j-1)|40$ so the only possible values for an odd  $p_j$ are $3,5,$ and $11.$

(ii). If $3|n$ then $E(3)=1$ Otherwise  $3|3^{E(3)-1}|40, $ implying $3|40.$ Similarly if $11|n$ then $E(11)=1.$

(iii). If $5|n$ then $E(5)\le 2.$ Otherwise $5^2|5^{E(5)-1}|40,$ implying $5^2|40.$

(iv). If $2|n$ then $E(2)\le 4.$  Otherwise $2^4|2^{E(2)-1}|40,$ implying $2^4|40.$

(v). By (i) we have  $$n=2^A3^B5^C11^D$$ where $A,B,C,D$ are non-negative integers. By (ii),  (iii), and (iv) we have   $A\le 4,\, B\le 1,\,C\le 2,\, D\le 1.$

(vi). If $A=4$ then $B=C=D=0.$ Otherwise $2^3|2^{A-1}$ and  at least one of the (even) terms $3^{B-1}(3-1),\, 5^{C-1}(5-1),\,11^{D-1}(11-1)\,$ would also occur  in the product for $\phi(n),$ implying $2^3\cdot 2=16|40.$

But if $A=4$ and $B=C=D=0$ then $n$ is a power of $2$ so $\phi(n)\ne 40.$

Therefore $A\le 3.$

(vii). If $D=0$ then $5|40=\phi(n)=\phi(2^A3^B5^C)$ which requires $C\ge 2.$ But by (ii) we have $C\le 2,$ so $D=0\implies C=2.$

If $D=1$ then $C\le 1$ otherwise $5^2|5^{C-1}(11-1)|\phi(n)=40,$ implying $5^2|40.$

(viii).  This narrows it to $16$ potential cases: $A\in \{0,1,2,3\}$ and $B\in \{0,1\}$ and $(C,D)\in \{(2,0),(1,1)\}.$ Now I will leave it to you to find which of these give  $n\ne 41$ and $\phi(n)=40.$